# How to fix "Type or namespace name 'X' does not exist in the namespace 'Y'" error in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

I am working in Azure Devops with a build pipeline for an ASP.NET web app.

Most settings leading up to the issue are pretty much the default settings, aside from the msbuild arguments in the build solution task, the build number, a powershell script at the beginning that should only be updating the version number, a command line task that I know isn't the cause since I added it after I first encountered the problem to deal with something else, and a couple of command line tasks simply displaying the contents of the D: folder.

The msbuild arguments are:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
/p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\" 
/p:UseWPP_CopyWebApplication=true /p:OutDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)" 
/p:Version=$(buildNumber)
```

The NuGet restore task is pointed to a feed in my Artifacts.  The feed contains MyPackage.problem, MyPackage.problem.blah (where blah represents several different names), MyPackage.Other1, MyPackage.Other2, MyPackage.Other3, MyPackage.Other4, and 3 other packages.  It's also getting a few packages from Nuget.org.

Everything seems to work fine until the build step, when I get the error

> The type or namespace name 'problem' does not exist in the namespace
>   'MyPackage' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

My first attempt to troubleshoot involved looking inside the problem packages, and they were significantly different from the other packages: they had a .csproj file and several .cs files in the main directory, as well as a few folders that the other packages didn't have, though the names and numbers differed between them, and they were missing a lib folder.  The other folders all seemed to be in order.

Update: not sure if this is relevant, but I took another look at the .nuspec files.  I compared the .nuspec file from the MyPackage.problem made in Azure Devops and compared it to a properly structured version from before we began switching over to Azure Devops (and before I was working on the project) and the .nuspec file from the unpacked repository.  They were identical, except in the first line the package made in Azure Devops had the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

While the others had:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

From what I've found online, the "encoding="utf-8"" is normally present, but the fact that it was absent in both the unpacked repository file and the properly structured package makes me think it might potentially be relevant somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to figure it out, or at least it seems I did.  The problem seemed to be that I was trying to use the Nuget Pack task to create the packages from the .nuspec files in the project which resulted in multiple separate packages due to the lack of a global .nuspec file.  I talked to my superior and asked how the packages were made normally, outside of Azure Devops, and he pointed me towards instructions detailing how to create a package from a .dll file.  Using a command line script task, I ran

```
nuget spec -AssemblyPath [path to .dll]
```

then used a copy files task to copy the .dll files (which had been created during the build solution task) from the build.artifactstagingdirectory to a lib/net40 folder in the working directory.  After that, I ran the Nuget pack task, targeting the .nuspec file created by the command line script, and the package was created successfully with the correct structure, aside from including the other folders that had been in the working directory, but these didn't seem to hinder the functionality, and it would likely be fairly simple to exclude them if needed.